Jumio kyc authentication failed (C010401)
I am currently trying to build a flutter module ekyc with jumio.
https://pub.dev/packages/jumio_mobile_sdk_flutter
I folllowed the setup steps, when I want to start the Jumio session, I got Authentication failed, with error code: C010401
Based on the jumio documentation:
C10401  Authentication failed   API credentials invalid, retry impossible


flutter: Error: 'PlatformException(C010401, Authentication failed, {errorCode: C010401, errorMessage: Authentication failed}, null)'.

I dont know what is the problem, I followed the docs:
received the response with the authorization_token
curl --location 'https://auth.emea-1.jumio.ai/oauth2/token'\
            -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET \
            --header 'Accept: application/json'\
            --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' 

It will be placed into the server side, but currently I just want to try out on the client. Here is the request:
 final dio = Dio();

    final String basicAuth = base64Encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'));

    try {
      final response = await dio.post(
        'https://auth.emea-1.jumio.ai/oauth2/token',
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic $basicAuth',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        ),
        data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.data['access_token'];
      }

This call succeeds, and I got back the result:
{"access_token":"eyJraWQiOi.....n_sGQ","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}

And I passed this token with EU datacenter into Jumio.init.
      await Jumio.init(accessToken, "EU");

(On the screenshot you can see I am on the eu site and there is the id and token with the right permissions)

Did I miss a step, I dont know why would it be unauthorized if the auth request calls with the clientId and the secret succeeds.

